# How to save to a child folder using Server.MapPath()

Tags: vb.net, server.mappath

I am creating a new PDF with iTextSharp and saving it to a folder on my server.
The following line of code will save it into the folder (called `XFolder` in the image below) containing my classes using `Server.MapPath()`:

```
Dim wri As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("myFile.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
```

I want to save my PDF in the folder that is inside `XFolder` (in `AFolder`):
[image: ![enter image description here]

I have tried:

```
Dim wri As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AFolder/myFile.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
```

but I get the exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path.......

How do I say "Save the PDF file into `AFolder`, which is a child of the current folder `XFolder`"?

Comment: Have you tried "AFolder/myFile.pdf" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use:

```
MapPath("AFolder/myFile.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you @tezzo, a simple problem but I really needed the extra help :)